# WordPress Map List Pro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Coming here is my last resort. I have already tried contacting the author of the plugin received no response.

I am using the Map List Pro Plugin that uses Google Maps to display pins on a map. I have this plugin installed two locations - my Beta site and the live site. The sites are identical but the plugin only works on the Beta site.

After looking at the Console in Google Chrome it appears as if the JS for Google Maps is having a loading issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCpLclBr3nawxJR3mVvjKQzCrRYVBoMjog&ver=4.6.2

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
at Object._.pg (js:86)
at new ug (js:87)
at new MapViewModel (maplistfront.js:633)
at Object.<anonymous> (maplistfront.js:2120)
at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (maplistfront.js:2117)
at i (jquery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)
```

This is the MapListPro JS file.

```
maplistfront.js:522 Uncaught TypeError: self.sortList is not a function
    at Object.success (maplistfront.js:522)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at y (jquery.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.b.onload.b.onreadystatechange (jquery.js:4)
```

A live version of it can be found here: http://beta.ctda.com/find-a-member/

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&#038;key=AIzaSyCpLclBr3nawxJR3mVvjKQzCrRYVBoMjog&#038;ver=4.6.2'></script>` Can you confirm that the key used on that tag, is your key not a copy and paste from some other site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `maplistfront.js` you have:

```
/*ViewModel*/
function MapViewModel(mapObject, mapid) {

    var self = this;

    self.mapID = mapid;
    self.MapHolder = $('#MapListPro' + self.mapID);
    self.mapCanvas = $('#map-canvas' + self.mapID);
```

When I opened your link I saw that `mapid` is `1` but that in your HTML you have:

```
<div class='prettyMapList above cf' id='MapListPro0'>
    <!--The Map -->
       <div id='map-canvas0' class='mapHolder'…
```

So `$('#MapListPro' + self.mapID)` ends up looking for `MapListPro1` instead of `MapListPro0`.

I really don't know anything about this Map List Pro plugin so I can't help in regards to why `mapId` is `1` instead of `0` (or why your HTML comes with `0` instead of `1`)

I hope this helps you find the root of the error. Cheers ~

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just hard coded the JS file to the map id being 0. I know that isn't a good solution but at least it will work temporarily.